# Finding match from a specific columns across two files

Tags: python, unix, match

I have two files of different length but both with 3 tab delimited columns. The number of lines for File2 is like 5,000,000,000 and number of lines in File1 is 2,000,000:

File1:

```
abc foo bar
lmn potato rst
lmp tomato  asd
```

File2:

```
123 asdasc  dad
032 foo 2134
123 linkin  9123
42  cads    asd
45654   tomato  12123
```

I need to use the 2nd column as the key for matching the two files and extract lines from File1 and File2 if there is a match on the 2nd column

```
fout = open('outfile', 'w')
with open('file1', 'r') as f1, open('file2', 'r') as f2:
  file2_keys = [i.split('\t')[1] for i in f2]
  for line in f1:
    if line.split('\t')[1] in file2_keys:
      print>>fout, line
```

But that only gives me the line from File1.

The desired output should be

Outfile2:

```
032 foo 2134
45654   tomato  12123
```

Outfile1:

```
abc foo bar
lmp tomato  asd
```

**Is there a way to do it in unix effectively?**  How else can this be done effectively?

Comment: The solution will most likely be quite different depending on language used. Please stick to a single language. Otherwise you might as well add all possible language tags.

Comment: Also, working with a file containing several gigabytes of data is always going to be slow. Before we can help you with the efficiency (which is a total different question from the main question) you have to specify your constraints.

Comment: You should be sorted by the second column two files in advance first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to do it in unix effectively?

You could make use of `awk`.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$2;next}{if ($2 in a) {print $0}}' File1 File2
```

would produce the desired output from `File1`:

```
032 foo 2134
45654   tomato 12123
```

Similarly,

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$2;next}{if ($2 in a) {print $0}}' File2 File1
```

would produce the desired output from `File2`:

```
abc foo bar
lmp tomato  asd
```

Answer (score 2):

Effectively? Use `awk` as 0xdeadbeef suggests or stick with C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <set>

int main() {

    std::string a, b, c;
    std::set<std::string> s;

    std::ifstream file1("File1");
    while (file1 >> a >> b >> c)
        s.insert(b);

    std::ifstream file2("File2");
    while (file2 >> a >> b >> c)
        if (s.count(b) != 0)
            std::cout << a << "\t" << b << "\t" << c << std::endl;

}
```

*Output*

```
032 foo 2134
45654   tomato  12123
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you added a python tag and tried it in python, here is a python's implementation:

```
fout1 = open('outfile1', 'w')
fout2 = open('outfile2', 'w')
with open('file1') as f1, open('file2') as f2:
    file2_lines = [i.strip() for i in f2]
    file2_keys = [i.split(' ')[1] for i in file2_lines]
    d = dict(zip(file2_keys, file2_lines))
    for line in f1:
        k = line.split(' ')[1]
        if k in d:
            print >>fout1, line.strip()
            print >>fout2, d[k]
fout1.close()
fout2.close()
```